# Do I need to #include anything in a file with function implementations if every needed library is included in my main?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, header-files

Okay so I am writing a program let's call it : `writing.c`
I have wrote two functions implementations in : `functions.c` and that's includes **only** `functions.h` (but I use printf and other functions which depend on `<stdio.h>` e.t.c but I do not include that here).

And then I have `writing.c` which has the main, and calls the functions and generally it is a completed program.
Here I have `#include` everything I need

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "help.h"
#include "functions.h"
```

It seems that the compiler doesn't recognize one of the functions in `functions.c`  when I compile `writing.c` it says:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘f1.."
```

Am I missing some #include here?

Comment: A good practice rule: the source files should include *directly* any headers they depend on, without relying on indirect inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

> "functions.c" and that's includes only "functions.h" (but I use printf
> and other functions which depend on <stdio.h> e.t.c but I do not
> icnlude that here).

You should `#include` all the files that a translation unit needs into that translation unit. Why do you deliberately *not* include them? Note that each translation unit (.c) file is first compiled *independently* from each other and only then linked together. The linking will find the *definitions* of unresolved symbols, but the declarations need to be present in each translation unit. So, in other words, what you include in your `main.c` has no bearing on whether `functions.c` will compile or not.

```
Short example to demonstate this:
//a.h
void f();

//a.c
#include 
void f()
{
    printf("hello");
}
```

no matter what the other files contain, this a.c file will not compile. Because when compiling this particular .c file, no other files (except those included into it, directly or indirectly) are considered.

Comment: Okay,thank you  I misunderstood something then. Something else: when you say that "Note that each translation unit (.c) file is first compiled independently from each other and only then linked together." . Then every file would need a main in order to compile , wouldn't it? For example If I got it right you say : I should include in functions.c every library is needed but if then still, would it compile individually ? without a main? (both functions are void)

Comment: @brucebanner. There is no requirement on a translation unit to have a main function. Only the program as a whole needs a main function. If you don't have a main function, you get a linker error, not a compiler error - each translation unit compiles just fine